# add a key=>value to all arrays in a 2D array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I would like to know if there is a quicker way to add the **same** `key=>value` pair to every inner array (2nd level) of a 2 dimensional array, other than using a `for` loop to cycle through every inner array?

**Background**

The array in question is a data set created with PDO, so am unsure how to inject this at the time of creation as it is not in the database.

Comment: you may make some cleaner looking code with built-in functions but the execution will be a `for` loop anyway.

Comment: You will need a loop of some kind, and a `for`/`foreach` is likely the fastest available. There are different ways you can dress that up, e.g. with `array_map`, but whether that's more performant is doubtful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(the first part of this should be comments - but for various reasons pre-pended to answer)

First off, PHP does not have multidimesional arrays - it has nested arrays which can **look** like multidimensional arrays.

Secondly, what are your criteria for "quicker"? Something which executes faster? Something that takes less time to implement? Something else?

While there are functions which operate on arrays, such as array_map(), and therefore require marginally less code than implementing a loop, they execute no faster than a PHP loop (indeed in some cases slower).

> it is not in the database

Why do you think that has got anything to do the problem? You can inject the value in the DML statement. Assuming its an SQL database and using MySQL syntax:

```
  SELECT mytable.*, 'value' AS `key`
  FROM mytable
  WHERE $somecondition
```

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't even thought of applying this to the SQL.